# Using react native prop type with flow

Tags: react-native, flowtype

is the the correct way to define **proptypes** for flow in **react-native**? I am looking for some guidelines.

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
  style?: StyleSheet.Styles,
  onPress: () => mixed,
  source: Image.propTypes.source
};

const IconButton = (props: Props) => (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
     <Image style={props.style} source={props.source} />
   </TouchableOpacity>
);

IconButton.defaultProps = {
  style: {}
};
```

export default IconButton;

How I use it is like this as an example:

```
<IconButton
    onPress={()=>{}}
    style={this.props.style}
    source={require('./assets/images/circle.png')}
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With flow, you don't necessarily need PropTypes - flow will take care of the input type checking for you.

However, if you still want the runtime warnings that PropTypes generates, you can use the [babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes) Babel plugin to automatically generate PropTypes based on your flow `Props` type definition.